# Android Firebase background notification not firing

Tags: android, json, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm developing an Android App that receives push notifications from Firebase.

I can get the token and send push notifications from Postman without any problem.

If the App is in foreground everything works as expected and I receive the payload in the onMessageReceived (I tested with various payloads).

But if I close the App it don't receive nothing. I tried with a lot of payloads, and I read all the documentation (diference between data and notification in payload).

Here's my classes that my project uses:

1 - The class that extends FirebaseMessagingService

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

private static final String TAG = "Android Push App";

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    sendNotification("Received notification");
}

private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.push_icon)
                    .setContentTitle("FCM Message")
                    .setContentText(messageBody)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

2 - The class that is responsible for get the token

```
public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

private static String TAG = "Android Push App";

@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {
    String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
}

private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Did obtained token");
    Log.d(TAG, token);
}
```

3 - My Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <action android:name="FIREBASE_ACTIVITY" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service android:name=".push.core.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <service
        android:name=".push.core.MyFirebaseMessagingService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
        android:resource="@drawable/push_icon" />

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
        android:resource="@color/colorAccent" />

</application>
```

4 - The MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
        for (String key : getIntent().getExtras().keySet()) {
            Object value = getIntent().getExtras().get(key);
            Log.d("MainActivity", "Key: " + key + " Value: " + value);
        }
    }
}
```

5 - Finally I tried this payload in the Postman

POST https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
Content-Type application/json
Authorization key=AIzaSy(...)kY

JSON Body (the examples I tried):

```
{
"to": "dxe0RDKbP...m9Uc","notification" : {
  "body" : "great match!",
  "title" : "Portugal vs. Denmark",
  "icon" : "push_icon",
  "sound" : "default"
}}
```

And:

```
{
"to": "dxe0RDKbP...m9Uc","notification" : {
  "body" : "great match!",
  "title" : "Portugal vs. Denmark",
  "icon" : "push_icon",
  "sound" : "default"
}}
```

And:

```
{
"to": "d3j-9OJ6R...C6w",
"notification" : {
    "title": "title",
    "body": "body"
},
"data": {
    "tipo": "normal"
}}
```

Also added the "priority" key and it doesn't work.

What I'm I doing wrong?

Thanks for all the help you can gave to me :)

**UPDATE**

Now it's working.

There was a conflict between the FireBaseMessagingService and a Geofence Push that is running (fired by the App).

After removed this Geofence service everything works as expected.

Also use the *notification* and *data* keys in the payload of the push.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

you must not put JSON key `'notification'` in your request to firebase API but instead use `'data'`.

**Example**

use this

```
{
  "to": "dxe0RDKbP...m9Uc",
  "data": {
    "body" : "great match!",
    "title" : "Portugal vs. Denmark",
    "icon" : "push_icon",
    "sound" : "default"
  }
}
```

**EDIT**
 you can try with only body and title

```
{
  "to": "dxe0RDKbP...m9Uc",
   "data": {
        "body" : "great match!",
        "title" : "Portugal vs. Denmark"
   }
}
```

**Edit New**

Add this in your manifest file `android:stopWithTask="false"` service property.

```
 <service
        android:name="com.yourapp.YourPushService"
        android:stopWithTask="false"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
 </service>
```

Comment: Stil not working. I had tried that payload. Can be something about the icon or sound?

Comment: @MichaelChaves please check my edit ans. and tell me what is the result of this.

Comment: If the App is in foreground or background it works fine. If I kill the App nothing happens

Comment: @MichaelChaves please check my edit new ans. add your service add android:stopWithTask="false" manifest file.

Comment: It's the same, not working. But I tried in the simulator and it's working. Maybe it''s related with the devices?

Comment: @MichaelChaves which device are you using.

Comment: @MichaelChaves if working fine please select my answer as correct.

Comment: @MichaelChaves i am glad happy to help you.

Answer (score 1):

you need to remove notification payload from the json and add a data payload to it. This is because Android has an inbuilt functionality of taking care of notification when it sees notification payload, i.e., it, whenever notification payload is sent android directly sends it to system dray and onMessageReceived function, is not called.

Answer (score 1):

As per the firebase documentation, Firebase notifications behave differently depending on the foreground/background state of the receiving app.

onMessageReceived is provided for most message types, with the following exceptions:

Notification messages delivered when your app is in the background. In this case, the notification is delivered to the device’s system tray. A user tap on a notification opens the app launcher by default.

Messages with both notification and data payload, both background and foreground. In this case, the notification is delivered to the device’s system tray, and the data payload is delivered in the extras of the intent of your launcher Activity.

So you need to remove notification payload from your json and only need to keep data payload to trigger onMessageReceived when app is in background.

Link:https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive